# How to do I set fancybox minHeight and maxHeight?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, fancyimpute, fancyupload

fancybox version: 2.1.0

description: I don't want to upgrade to version 3 because it will affect the others.

So how can the `minHeight` and `maxHeight` values be effective in the current version?

I tried the following method, but it didn't work.

```
//source code

$.fancybox.open({
            href: '#advancedSearchWrapper',
            maxHeight: 500,
            minHeight: 300,
            fitToView: true,
            autoSize: true,
            modal: true,
            autoScale: true,
)}
```

Answer (score -1):

To make `minHeight` and `maxHeight` options effective you need to set `autoSize` option to `false`.

```js
$.fancybox.open({
  href: '#divContent',
  maxHeight: 150,
  minHeight: 100,
  fitToView: true,
  autoSize: false,
  modal: true,
  autoScale: true,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fancybox@2.1.7/dist/css/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fancybox@2.1.7/dist/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<div id="divContent">
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content
  Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content Content...
</div>
```